# Grease Monkey Script doesn't run - first script attempt

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

O.k so I've created a little script that I want to change the formatting of a table row based on the data in some  tags on the page, offline the script works fine but I'm tryingt o adapt it to provide as a Userscript for greasemonkey, firstly my script wont install via the site, secondly when I install locally using "new user script" it appears to do nothing, nothing is logged to the console either, heres my code:

```
// // ==UserScript==
// @name    Cerberus Time-since Row Colouring
// @author  David Duke, Luke Mulholland-Helme-Kelsall 
// @description Looks for ABBR tags and their title parameter, and then calculates the time difference between Now and the timestamps. The parent table row then has an appropraite CSS class added to it based on the time difference calculated.
// @include http://{removed url}/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js

// ==/UserScript==
$(document).ready(function(){
$('abbr').each(function(index){
    var _then = Date.parse($(this).attr('title'));
    var _now = new Date().getTime();
    _then = _then.getTime();            
    var a_minute = 60000;
    if(_now < _then + (a_minute*30)){
        $(this).parent(tr).css("background-color","green");
    } else if(_now < _then + (a_minute*60)){
        $(this).parent(tr).css("background-color","yellow");
    } else {
        $(this).parent(tr).css("background-color","red");
    }
    console.log("title:" + $(this).attr('title') + ",_then:"+_then+",_now:"+_now);
});
});
```

Any help on this would be great because I'm racking my brains, could be related to the @require part, but from what I find on google that should be enough to use the functions within those scripts.

Comment: Versions of everything?  Look in the script's directory, `under {FF profile folder}/gm_scripts`.  Are jquery.min.js and date.js there?  If so, the requires are working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
// @include http://{removed url}/*
```

If your actual script matches that, it might be the problem... I read somewhere that missing white spaces causes problems...

Try this:

```
// @include     http://{removed url}/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
```

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is, you have commented out, what is supposed to be, GM scipt declaration.

Instead of

```
// // ==UserScript==
// @name    Cerberus Time-since Row Colouring
// @author  David Duke, Luke Mulholland-Helme-Kelsall 
// @description Looks for ABBR tags and their title parameter, and then calculates the time difference between Now and the timestamps. The parent table row then has an appropraite CSS class added to it based on the time difference calculated.
// @include http://{removed url}/*
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require     http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js

// ==/UserScript==
```

Use:

```
// ==UserScript==
@name    Cerberus Time-since Row Colouring
@author  David Duke, Luke Mulholland-Helme-Kelsall 
@description Looks for ABBR tags and their title parameter, and then calculates the time difference between Now and the timestamps. The parent table row then has an appropraite CSS class added to it based on the time difference calculated.
@include http://{removed url}/*
@require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
@require     http://www.datejs.com/build/date.js

// ==/UserScript==
```

That will fix your issues of script detection or installation.

Comment: All newly created userscripts have that block commented, it is supposed to be that way - except for MAYBE the first one where ==userscript== is commented twice.......   the missing white spaces in the @include line COULD cause problems though.